# Getting date as a String from android

Tags: java, android

I made this little function:

```
public String getDay() {

    String day = (String)android.text.format.DateFormat.format("E", new    java.util.Date());
    return day; 
}
```

I know that the `android.text.format.DateFormat.form("E", new java.util.Date());` Returns a CharSequence, but is there any problem regarding casting this from a sequence of char's?

I used the function like this:

```
String day = getDay();
if(day == "Tue") {
        Toast.makeText(TaxiFaresActivity.this, day + " inside the if", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    }
```

But it seems to me that I ever get into the function?

If I but the Toast outside, I get the following Toast

> Tue

Which is right? Why doesn't the program jumps right into the if-sentence?

Comment: compare Strings by equals (day.equals("Tue"))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In java == means you are comparing addresses not content so use equals when comparing objects:

```
if(day.equals("Tue"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should compare strings using `.equals()` I guess?

See for instance: http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/strings/12stringcomparison.html

> compare Strings for equality, don't use ==. The == operator checks
> to see if two objects are exactly the same object. Two strings may be
> different objects, but have the same value (have exactly the same
> characters in them). Use the .equals() method to compare strings for
> equality. Similarly, use the .compareTo() method to test for unequal
> comparisons. \
>
> For example,
> String s = "something", t = "maybe something else";
> if (s == t)      // Legal, but usually WRONG.
> if (s.equals(t)) // RIGHT
> if (s > t)    // ILLEGAL
> if (s.compareTo(t) > 0) // CORRECT>

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
if(day.matches("tue"))
{
    Toast.makeText(TaxiFaresActivity.this, day + " inside the if", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Or You can Use

```
if(day.contentEquals("tue"))
    {
        Toast.makeText(TaxiFaresActivity.this, day + " inside the if", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Try this
These functions are very accurate for matching string.